# Deploy ruby on rails application to multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I am currently working on a Ruby on Rails application and deploying it to two separate servers with a load balancer between. My problem is that when attempting to login (connecting to database) one server works correctly while the other throws up the following error;

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:

It is listing the following line as the problem;

```
@dbh = DBI.connect(connection_string, @auth['username'], @auth['password'], DRIVER)
```

I have done some research and found reference to the location of jar files being a possible issue though i have included the gems-gems-jdbc-jtds-1.3.0.1-lib-jtds-1.3.0.jar in tomcat/lib and WEB-INF/lib. In addition to resolving this issue i was wondering if both deployments are the same so should the error not appear on both or neither. Any questions or further information needed feel free to let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I resolved this by adding gems-gems-jdbc-jtds-1.3.0.1-lib-jtds-1.3.0.jar into /var/lib/tomcat8/lib. For some reason when deploying the war file this jar didnt unpack in the ROOT/lib folder. Works fine now.